How can a Spring Boot SSL Bundle be created on demand
I have a Spring Boot SSL Bundle defined as follows
spring:
  ssl:
    bundle:
      watch:
        file:
          quiet-period: 20s
      pem:
        fos-internal-cert-bundle:
          reload-on-update: ${INTERNAL_CERT_RELOAD:true}
          keystore:
            certificate: ${INTERNAL_CERT:classpath:cert/client-certificate.pem}
            private-key: ${INTERNAL_CERT_PRIVATE_KEY:classpath:cert/private.key}


This SSL bundle is used in Rest Template as follows:
@Bean("restTemplateWithCertificate")
  public RestTemplate restTemplateWithBdfCertificate(
      RestTemplateBuilder builder, RestClientProperties clientProperties, SslBundles sslBundles) {
    SslBundle sslBundle = sslBundles.getBundle("fos-internal-cert-bundle");
    return builder
        .requestFactory(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.class)
        .additionalInterceptors(new HeaderRequestInterceptor())
        .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(clientProperties.getReadTimeoutSec()))
        .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(clientProperties.getConnectionTimeoutSec()))
        .setSslBundle(sslBundle)
        .build();
  }

The certificates that I am using are updated by a cron job and auto reloaded, as shown in the YAML fragment. I had the following questions:

Does the Rest Template bean automatically load the new certificate.
We have a situation where the cron job occasionally malfunctions and we need to have fall back design that will look like this. Is it create a new instance of the SSL Bundle and update the Singleton bean? Or should it be destroyed and recreated? (I know this is not possibly the most robust design

try{
 use restTemplate to call remote svc
} catch Exception {
   if SSL certificate expires, fetch updated certificate through an API
   call the remote svc again
}


Spring Boot will not automatically reload new certificates for RestTemplates. As stated in the documentation, reloading only works for Tomcat and Netty embedded web servers. It does not work for any type of client connection. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/features/ssl.html#features.ssl.reloading
